# Need change inside htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect

i have following htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !^/?(maintenance\.html|.*\.css|.*\.js)$ http://www.example.com/maintenance.html [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ index.php 
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
```

as you can see all, no matter which page you visit on the website it will be redirected to maintenance.html. I also need a small change that will exclude one more location from this. Since I am using Magento, I need to exclude admin area from this redirect so I think these are the urls that I need

http://www.example.com/index.php/admin_852_in

http://www.example.com/skin/

http://www.example.com/js/

http://www.example.com/media/

What rule should I add for these two urls too?

thanks!

Comment: Is it not just: `RewriteRule !^/?(maintenance\.html|.*\.css|.*\.js|admin*)$ http://www.example.com/maintenance.html [R=302,L]`?

Comment: it happens nothing. I need that admin area works ok too without the redirect

Comment: Any reason you are not using the maintenance.flag mechanism built-in Magento ? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31840/how-do-i-enable-version-1-9-maintenance-flag-with-admin-access

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak your exclusions like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !^/?(maintenance\.html$|index\.php/admin|css/|js/|.*\.(css|js)$) http://www.example.com/maintenance.html [R=302,L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, one small help. Can you please look at updated question, dont neeed /admin/ only /admin_852_in/ an few more links to allow. Would be more then thankful.